# How to write SQL query to get emp name and manager name which is in same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an `Employee` table:

[image: Employee]

where `EmpID` is the primary key and ManagerID is a foreign key.

I want output like this, if manager id is null then display "No Manager":

[image: Output]

I wrote this query

```
SELECT 
    e1.EmpID, 
    e1.EmpName, 
    e1.ManagerID,
    ManagerName = CASE 
                     WHEN e1.ManagerID = NULL THEN 'No Manager'
                     ELSE e2.EmpName
                  END
FROM 
    Emp e1
LEFT JOIN 
    Emp e2 ON e1.ManagerID = e2.EmpID;
```

But I'm getting this output, I want 'No Manager' in place of NULL

[image: wrong output]

Please help,

Thanks in advance

Comment: `!= NULL`? or `IS NOT NULL`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `!=` with `NULL`!  The correct syntax would be `IS NOT NULL`.  However, use the built-in function `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT e1.EmpID, e1.EmpName, e1.ManagerID,
       ManagerName = COALESCE(e2.EmpName, 'No Manager')
FROM Emp e1 LEFT JOIN
     Emp e2
    ON e1.ManagerID = e2.EmpID;
```

Almost any operation on `NULL` returns `NULL`, including `=` and `<>`.  Two prominent exceptions are `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

> `NULL` mean unknow

Try to use `IS NULL` instead of `= NULL`

```
SELECT 
    e1.EmpID, 
    e1.EmpName, 
    e1.ManagerID,
    ManagerName = CASE WHEN e1.ManagerID IS NULL THEN 'No Manager'
                       ELSE e2.EmpName
                       END
FROM Emp e1 LEFT JOIN Emp e2 ON e1.ManagerID = e2.EmpID;
```

**NOTE**

The [SET ANSI_NULLS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) default is on

> Specifies ISO compliant behaviour of the Equals (=) and Not Equal To (<>) comparison operators when they are used with null values in SQL Server 2017.

If you want to use `NULL = NULL` you can change the setting, although I would not suggest about it.

Here is a table for `SET ANSI_NULLS`

```
Boolean Expression  SET ANSI_NULLS ON   SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
    NULL = NULL         UNKNOWN             TRUE
    1 = NULL            UNKNOWN             FALSE
    NULL <> NULL        UNKNOWN             FALSE
    1 <> NULL           UNKNOWN             TRUE
    NULL > NULL         UNKNOWN             UNKNOWN
    1 > NULL            UNKNOWN             UNKNOWN
    NULL IS NULL        TRUE                TRUE
    1 IS NULL           FALSE               FALSE
    NULL IS NOT NULL    FALSE               FALSE
    1 IS NOT NULL       TRUE                TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked too.